# Flutter swift plugin creating and showing an arbitrary UIViewController

Tags: swift, flutter

I'd like to show a swift `UIViewController` in a flutter app. So far, I successfully :

- wrote a 'programmatic' `UIViewController`
- used another full swift iOS app to test that I could `self.present` this view
- wrote a flutter plugin, and I tested that I can exchange data fine between this plugin and my flutter app.

Now, inside this plugin, I can instantiate my CustomViewController, but I have no way to show it on screen, because I'm writing a `FlutterPlugin`, and it obviously doesn't have any of the facilities like `self.window`, `self.present`, etc. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the current rootController from the keyWindow and present your custom view controller from there.

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(...
```

Comment: Any Idea how to get back to flutter?